# Обьясните пожалуйста как работает перебор массива в данном случае?

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, циклы, for

1) Как это работает? Цикл начинает с 0-го элемента, и идет до i-го при этом i уже равняется 0, по идее он должен сразу же завершится? никак разобраться не могу, ничего толкового по тому поводу не нашел... Но работает так, словно проходится по каждому элементу.

2) Не пойму суть работы тела цикла, что именно увеличивает значение?

```
char str[255];
int chars[256] = {0};

for(int i=0; str[i]; i++)
    chars[str[i]]++;
```

Comment: что такое `arr` в условии цикла? Вы не объявляете его.

Comment: @Bogdan опечатка была, исправил.

Comment: "...и идет до i-го" - откуда вы это взяли? Почему вы решили, что этот цикл "идет до i-го"? "что именно увеличивает значение" - о каком значении идет речь?

Comment: Цикл for работает до тех пор, пока значение во втором его параметре истинно. В данном случае вторым является `str[i]`. Любая преременная (или элемент массива) стоящие сами по себе расцениваются как значение этой переменной (или элемента массива). Таким образом цикл работает до тех пор пока str[i] не равно 0. Т.е. до тех пор пока мы двигаясь по строке не найдем в ней нулевой байт. Данная конструкция не безопасна, она выйдет за пределы массива если в нем вдруг не окажется нулевого байта

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char str[255];` // Никак не инициализируется, поэтому, если это не глобальная переменная, то в ней мусор. Если глобальная. то нули.

```
int chars[256] = {0}; // Явно требуется инициализация и предыдущему массиву.
```

Что касается условия цикла, то исходя из неинициализированной переменной, массива, цикл может либо не выполниться ни разу, либо выполнятся пока не встретит ноль.

```
for(int i=0; str[i]; i++)
```

Что касается инкремента, то в данном случае инкрементируется значение элемента массива `chars` по индексу значения `str[i]`.

```
chars[str[i]]++;
```

Другими словами, например, берется значение элемента  str[0], которое, допустим, равно 1, затем берется значение chars[1], которое в данном случае ноль и увеличивается на единицу. В общем, производится изменение значений по заданным позициям. Где `str` задает позиции, и затем в цикле меняет значения в `chars`.